# Pyscript taking forever to load after importing pygame

Tags: python, html, pygame, pyscript

So, I'm using PyScript for my website. Using Live Server, my website is taking forever to load after I try to install pygame. My PyScript code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PyScript TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <py-env>
    - pygame
</py-env>

  <body>
    <py-script src="Game.py">

    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, and note that this only happens when I install pygame, it just says this for (at what seems to be the case at this rate) forever:

Loading runtime... Runtime created... Initializing components...

What can I do about this? It is very frustrating.

Comment: Pygame isn't currently supported by PyScript or Pyodide. [Source](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/packages-in-pyodide.html)

Answer (score 1):

As @SimonUnderwood noted, PyGame isn't currently supported by Pyodide/PyScript. Libraries that aren't purely Python need to have their C/Rust/Fortran/etc extensions pre-compiled to run in [Web Assembly](https://webassembly.org/), and other adjustments may be required as well.

That said, one thing that will help with issues like this in the future is to use a more recent version of PyScript. The `alpha` release dates to May 2022; the most recent release at time of writing is [2023.03.1](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/releases), released March 2023 as the notation implies, and [2023.05.1 Release Candidate 1](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/discussions/1489) just went public. In these more-recent versions of PyScript, trying to load a non-viable package will present an error message at the top of the page like:

```
(PY1001): Unable to install package(s) 'pygame'. 
Reason: Can't find a pure Python 3 Wheel for package(s) 'pygame'.
See: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#micropip-can-t-find-a-pure-python-wheel for more information.
```